# Global Messaging service in Angular problems

Tags: angular, angular-services

i am working on a web app using angular 7, and currently i am trying to use the Api interceptor to display an alert that an error has occured, which is working fine however, after adding the messaging service and messaging component, i tried to push the error message using the messaging(to format the message as i want in the component's template) however, it is not working and it is not giving me any errors. Anyway, here is the code

**Api Interceptor.ts**

```
    return next.handle(apiReq).pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      //client Side Error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      //server side
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }

    window.alert(errorMessage);
    console.log('An Error has Occured');
    this.messageService.add(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

This is the last part of the intecept and the beginning part of the handleError method.

**message.service.ts**

```
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

**messages.component.ts**

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public messageService:MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**messages.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="messageService.messages.length">

  <h2>Messages</h2>
  <button class="clear"
          (click)="messageService.clear()">clear</button>
  <div *ngFor='let message of messageService.messages'> {{message}} </div>

</div>
```

My goal is to display the error messages dynamically formatted in the messages.component and pushed by the service that is injected in the Api Interceptor.

Thank you

Comment: it's correctly pushed, but the html is not updated, that's your issue?

Comment: yes! i am messing with my Urls to produce an error, however, it is not being updated in the DOM

Comment: You should use observable instead of a normal variable in your service.  ` messages$: Observable<string[]>` and then in your component you can subscribe to this observable  `<div *ngFor='let message of messageService.messages$ | async'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Subject` in your `messageService` as follows, when ever an error gets added to the `messages` array you should call the `next()` method with messages array.

```
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];
  messages$: new Subject<any>();

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
    this.messages$.next(this.messages);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

In your component, you should update the DOM whenever a change a message gets added to the messages array so you have to subscribe to the `message$` subject as follows

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  public messages: Array<any> = [];
  constructor(public messageService:MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.messages$.subscribe(messages => this.messages = messages);
  }

}
```

you html should be

```
<div *ngIf="messages.length">

  <h2>Messages</h2>
  <button class="clear"
          (click)="messageService.clear()">clear</button>
  <div *ngFor='let message of messages'> {{message}} </div>

</div>
```